# Shiny fluidRow has no effect

Tags: r, shiny

Any idea why the slider and dropdown options in the side-panel are not on the same row?

```
require(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("problem"), 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                 textInput(inputId = 'input', label = 'input'),
                 tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("panel 1", 
                            br(),
                            fluidRow(
                              sliderInput('smooth', 'Smooth', 0, 5, 3, step = 1, width='20%'),
                              selectInput("option", "Choose a option", choices = c("option 1", "option 2"), width='40%')
                            )
                            , width='100%'),
                   tabPanel("panel 2", verbatimTextOutput("summary"))
                 )
    ),
    mainPanel(width = 8, p('main panel'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fluidRow` will require `column` to be defined to show the layout as you desire. In your case following will work:

```
fluidRow(
            column(4,
                   sliderInput('smooth', 'Smooth', 0, 5, 3, step = 1)
                   ),
            column(4,
                   selectInput("option", "Choose a option", choices = c("option 1", "option 2"))
                   )
          )
```

`column(4,` is the width of each column.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
require(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("problem"), 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                 textInput(inputId = 'input', label = 'input'),
                 tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("panel 1", 
                            br(),
                            fluidRow(
                              div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 49%;",sliderInput('smooth', 'Smooth', 0, 5, 3, step = 1)),
                              div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 49%;",selectInput("option", "Choose a option", choices = c("option 1", "option 2")))
                            )
                            , width='100%'),
                   tabPanel("panel 2", verbatimTextOutput("summary"))
                 )
    ),
    mainPanel(width = 8, p('main panel'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers, but a fully shiny solution preferred :)